# Display Icon instead True/False in datagridview in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview in a Windows form that shows content of table of database, 
one column of table type is boolean, so in datagridview shows true/false, 
but i want to customize it to show Icon or image like Accepted, or Rejected icons. Those Icons I have them in my Project Resources
This is my code

```
var cars = (from u in db.Cars
             .......... 
           select new
           {
           .....
           .....                                                
           Approved = u.Treated == true ? Resources.approved : Resources.Cancel  // Here Not working

           }).ToList();
           if (cars != null)
           {
             dgvCars.DataSource = null;
             dgvCars.DataSource = cars;

            }
```

In Approved cell I want to show one of those icons, depending true or false. I did as you see in my code

```
Approved = u.Treated == true ? Resources.approved : Resources.Cancel
```

but not working. Maybe I have to code somthing in my Fomatingcell events but I have no idea how to do that. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridViewImageColumn` is able to display images.
By default `DataGridView` automatically generates columns based on value type. `DataGridViewImageColumn` will be generated by default if value is array of bytes (`byte[]`).

In your case the type is different. You can solve in two ways

First:
Convert images to byte arrays.

Second:
Create image column manually and bind it to the image property.

```
// Execute it once when initializing datagridview
var approvedColumn = new DataGridViewImageColumn
{
    Name = "dgvCars_Approved",
    HeaderText = "Approved",
    DataPropertyName = "Approved", // This will bound column to the property of the object
};
dgvCars.Columns.Add(approvedColumn);

// DataGridView will automatically pick up correct image
var cars = (
    from u in db.Cars
    .......... 
    select new
    {
       .....
       .....                                                
       Approved = u.Treated == true ? Resources.approved : Resources.Cancel
    }).ToList();

    // Check for null is redundant, because ToList() never returns null
    // Because cars is a new instance 
    // set .DataSource to null before actual value is redundant as well

    dgvCars.DataSource = cars;
```

Second approach will mess up a little bid with autogenerated columns, but I would suggest to create all required columns manually via designer or manually with code.
Predefined columns will provide more control over view behaviour and flexibility.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I get following error. "Unable to create a constatnt value of type ´system.Drawing.Bitmap´. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"  This is the same error I got when I tried only with Approved = u.Treated == true ? Resources.approved : Resources.Cancel